# How to specify a background image for different sizes when mapping an array to component?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

How to show a background image for different sizes using a variable?

```
{posts.map((post) =>
  <div className={`bg-[url('${post.smallImage}')] md:bg-[url('${post.largeImage}')]`}
)}
```

This breaks with a very strange error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './${post.smallImage}'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/globals.css
```

If I log `post.smallImage` it logs the image path correctly: `'/pic1.png'`
And if I don't use the variable it displays the image correctly:

```
{posts.map((post) =>
  <div className={`bg-[url('/pic1.png')] md:bg-[url('pic2.png')]`}
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './${post.smallImage}'
```

comes from webpack, because it tries to resolve path to whatever is inside `url()` and import it as an asset.

[Tailwind docs](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html) recommend to avoid generating Tailwind classes with JavaScript. Code must be statically analyzable, or "purgeable":

> it is important to avoid dynamically creating class strings in your
> templates with string concatenation, otherwise PurgeCSS won’t know to
> preserve those classes.

In this situation, looks like it would be more efficient to use `<img>` with `srcset` attribute instead. Like this:

```
{posts.map((post, index) => (
  <img key={index} src={post.smallImage} srcset={`${post.smallImage} 768px, ${post.largeImage}`} />
))}
```